# Installing extension packs to a virtual machine

Tags: usb, virtualbox, extension

I am using a windows 7 laptop and I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS inside the oracle VM virtualbox(v 5.1.12). I am trying to install an extension pack so that I can access the USB port from the virtual machine. I downloaded the suitable pack(5.1.12) from [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/) but on trying to open it in Ubuntu, I am getting an error saying archive type is not supported. What should I do?

Comment: You need .deb files for Debian/Ubuntu. And, of course, you need the exact same version number as your installed Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VirtualBox expansion pack is opened with VBox in the Windows host.

In Windows Explorer, right click the .exe file and select "Open with" then "VirtualBox Manager".

It should only take a few seconds to run.